# typeerror unsupported operand type(s) for / 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the average score from a list if three numbers, as shown below:

```
a = (lines.split(":")[1].split(",")[-3:])
Print (a)
Averagescore = sum(a)/len(a)
Print (averagescore)
```

Then it says:
typeerror unsupported operand type(s) for / 'str' and 'int'

Comment: The errror message is pretty clear. And there's no `Print`, only `print`.

Comment: Can you atleast tell me what the problem is?

Comment: You need to convert the strings in `a` into numbers in order to do arithmetic with them.

Comment: How can you do that then?

Comment: I'm not sure how it even gets that far, shouldn't it fail inside of `sum`  with `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` ?

Comment: @RyanHaining: Yes, it should fail inside of sum. It's a mystery wrapped in an enigma. :)

Comment: @NickCollins: You should put some typical input data into your question. Are these numbers whole numbers, or decimals?

Comment: @RyanHaining: The _only_ way I can think of `sum()` not raising a `TypeError` is if `a` is an empty list.

Comment: OTOH, if `a` is an empty list it would sum to zero, and so there _still_ wouldn't be the "unsupported operand type(s) for / 'str' and 'int'" error. Hmmm.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the error message as you describe may not be accurate for this code, but nonetheless, the issue is that you are trying to treat a list of strings as a list of ints. for example

```
>>> s = "1 16 32" # string
>>> s.split() # this returns a list of strings
['1', '16', '32']
>>> s.split()[0] + 1 # you can't add an int to a string
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

If you want to treat them as ints (or floats) then you will need to add the conversion as in

```
a = [int(n) for n in s.split()]
a = [float(n) for n in s.split()] # alternatively
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, the reason why it baffled me was because I was able to extract the highest score from it as integer. Thankyou for that its very much appreciated

Comment: @NickCollins : Are you _sure_ that your highest score extraction works properly? Beware of using `max()` or `min()` on numbers in string form - if the number strings don't all have the same amount of digits then the result won't be what you expect, since, for example, `'10' < '2'`.

Comment: Yes im aware of that, I think its because it had key=int at the end of it

Comment: @NickCollins: Ah, ok. Yes, supplying `int` as the key function to `max` (or `sort`) will give you the correct result. But it's better in this case to convert your whole list to `int` and then find the maximum of those `int`s, because you need the whole list as `int`s anyway to find the average. So it's a little bit wasteful to tell `max` to use the `int` key function, since it's basically making a private list of `int`s so it can find the maximum and then throwing that private list away.